# Could not install node.js on ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I am having trouble to install `node.js` latest version on ubuntu 14.04. I am following the below steps.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But when I am checking the node version like `node -v` its giving me the below error.

```
bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory
```

Here I need to install the `node.js and npm` latest version on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can lost package and You run command:

```
LPB_Tandn_IT:~ tannetto$ apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

and `nodejs` worked again!
and If not worked, You can create symlink:

Doing a symlink solves the issue: `ln -s /usr/sbin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node`.